Does BIP86 not use a unique prefix for extended keys?
Do BIP86 extended keys not use a unique prefix?
For example:

BIP44 = xprv/xpub
BIP49 = yprv/ypub
BIP84 = zprv/zpub
BIP 86 = xprv/xpub?

In other words, do BIP86 extended keys share the same serialization format as BIP44?

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/121347/208, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/89281/208

@PieterWuille Thank you.

Hi Greg, if one of the links that Pieter provided resolved your question, would you please vote to close it as a duplicate of that one? Otherwise, could you perhaps edit your question to clarify what part of it remains unanswered?
